# SQL Server - Transactional Replication (partial data only)

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have 6 months of data, how do I replicate only the most current 3 months of data to the subscribers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use filtered replication.  When you read examples about filtered replication, you'll probably see it referring to a branch office scenario where a single central office stores data for several branch offices, and each branch only wants to replicate their own data.  It involves creating filters on a key, and in your case, you'll want to use your date range as the key.

Here's an [article on filtered replication with transactional replication](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Creating_Transactional_Replication_Publications), and another on [filtering with merge replication](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Creating_Merge_Replication_Publications).